# Find a specific sequence in all the rows of a 2d array

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a loop in python (or more pythonic way) to detect when a specific sequence happens in a 2d array and then replace it with another set. Specifically finding the first [0,1,1] in each row and replace it with something like [0.25,0.5,0.75] to create a gradient on the edge of the 1's.

Example:

```
a =[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,0]
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,0]
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

detectfunction(a,[0,1,1],[0.25,0.5,0.75])

output =[[0,  0 ,  0 ,  0,0,0,0]
        [0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1,0]
        [0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1,0]
        [0,  0 ,  0 ,  0,0,0,0]]
```

This is my current code that only works in like one section of the data. The fringe list is what im really trying to cut into after the 0,1 transition.

```
fr_len = 10
fringe = np.arange(0,1,1/fr_len)
fringecloud1 = []
for ind,val in enumerate(O1bitcloud_m):
    m = list(O1bitcloud_m[ind])
    if val[ind] == 0 and val[ind+1] == 1:
        startind = ind
        endind = ind+fr_len
        m[startind:endind] = fringe
        fringecloud1.append(m)
    else:
        fringecloud1.append(m)
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: In your example, the pattern `[0, 1, 1]` cannot overlap with itself. What is the expected output if we allow for overlapping patterns, e.g. substituting `[0, 1, 0]` in `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]`?

Comment: This is specific to the case [0,1,1] in reality its going to be something like [0,0,0......0,1,1,1,1,1,....] with tons of zeros before tons of ones and then back to zeros.

Comment: I understand that this is a simplified example. My point was that there can be different ways to perform the substitution. By the way, `scipy.ndimage` module could be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using the builtin `array` module. By representing rows of `a` as Python arrays, we can directly call `replace` on the bytes representing each row. The result does not match your expected output exactly (I am not sure why there are leading zeros in rows 2 and 3 of you example output).

```
a =[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],]

import array

def detectfunction(a, pattern, subst):
  pattern_bytes = array.array('d', pattern).tobytes()
  subst_bytes   = array.array('d', subst).tobytes()
  
  result = list()
  for row in a:
    arr_row = array.array('d', row)
    new_arr_row = array.array('d', [])
    new_arr_row.frombytes(arr_row.tobytes().replace(pattern_bytes, subst_bytes))
    result.append(new_arr_row.tolist())
  
  return result

result = detectfunction(a,[0,1,1],[0.25,0.5,0.75])

# [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
#  [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
#  [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
#  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Comment: This is great! It worked perfectly! After I did it with this direction instead of writing a new function for this (which i might need to anyway) I filled my data 90,180,270 degrees to do it on all four sides. I got some streaking where they overlap but I think I can fix that

Comment: Good to hear. Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem. I also think there is some scope for optimization, especially if you input array has a very special form (zeros followed by ones followed by zeros).

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the operation in three tasks and the relative method:

1. Getting groups of n consecutive elements, to be compared with the target;
2. Find the index of the target group, first match;
3. Replace the target group with the replacement.

---

Here the first method which is a generator returning a list with element grouped by `n`:

```
def each_cons(iterable, n = 2):
    if n < 2: n = 1
    i, size = 0, len(iterable)
    while i < size-n+1:
        yield iterable[i:i+n]
        i += 1
```

---

The second method, to get the index:

```
def find_idx_for_target(lst, target):
    for idx, sub in enumerate(each_cons(lst, n=len(target))):
        if sub == target:
            return idx
    return None
```

---

Finally the replacement:

```
def replace(lst, target, replacement):
    for sublst in lst:
        idx = find_idx_for_target(sublst, target)
        if idx is not None:
            sublst[idx:idx+len(replacement)] = replacement
    # add a check for len(target) == len(replacement)
```

---

Example:

```
a =[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0,1,1]]
target = [0, 1, 1]
replacement = [0, 2, 2]

replace(a, target, replacement)

a

#[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
# [0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0],
# [0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0],
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2]]
```